# How to make a countdown/Timer for a game PHP/JS

Tags: javascript, php, timer

I have created many text based webgames in my days, and I always used PHP, JS and MySQL.

One thing I never understood is how to create the "timer" between actions. Lets say it's a game where you rob banks. Once you click "Rob bank" a countdown starts, for lets say 2 minutes. And under those 2 minutes you can not Rob the bank again until those 2 minutes has passed.
Is it possible to make this kind of countdown/timer system with php & javascript?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Look up the setTimeout() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to save a timestamp somewhere on your server, and send it to your clients. Let's take the example with the bank:

I assume you have multiple banks, and stored them in a database, is that correct? If so, once a user starts robbing this bank, you set a `startRobTimestamp` to this bank. The users now can only rob this bank again, if the current timestamp is 2minutes bigger than the `startRobTimestamp`.

This is of course very basic, but the exact implementation depends very much on your data handling.

Comment: I actually thought of this as I wrote the question. I think this would be one of the best solutions.
Obviously the player should not be able to manipulate the timer, and I feel this would be quite safe since the timestamp is in the database. And php is checking the time on the server compared to the timestamp, must be quite safe?

Comment: Yes, as a general rule you want to have client- and server side checks, this way manipulating the timestamp is (almost) impossible for the players

Answer (score 0):

This might help: http://www.sitepoint.com/build-javascript-countdown-timer-no-dependencies/

You can then monitor the actual variables and keep robbing banks disabled till all are equal to 0.

Comment: Yeah. You definitely want to make the actual start time from the server, pass that to js to show the countdown. If the user sets it to 0 via the console the server can throw an error saying there is still x time remaining.